# Python Username and Password box label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a tkinter window that asks the user for a username and password. My problem: I can't get the Username and Password labels aligned properly next to the entry boxes. They both sit on top of the entry fields. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the labels to be on the left of the entry fields? Here's my code:

```
#Import Tkinter module
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

#Create a window
tk1 = Tk()

#Window Size
tk1.geometry("500x500")

#Title window
tk1.title("Username and Password")

#Set background color using hex code
tk1.configure(background = "#618f56")

#Create a Label
lbl = Label(tk1, text="Welcome! Please enter your Username and Password.", bg="#618f56")

#Create a UN entry box
ent1 = Entry(tk1)
lbl1 = Label(tk1, text="Username")

#Create a Password entry box
ent2 = Entry(tk1)
lbl2 = Label(tk1, text="Password")

#Create a button
btn = Button(tk1, text="Submit", bg="#ffffff")

#Widgets
lbl.pack()
lbl1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
ent1.pack()
ent2.pack()
btn.pack()

#Draw window and start application
tk1.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')

        # Labels
        first_Label = Label(self.root, text='First Label')
        second_Label = Label(self.root, text='Second Label')

        # Entries
        first_entry = Entry(self.root)
        second_entry = Entry(self.root)



        # Packing
        first_Label.grid(column=1, row=1)
        second_Label.grid(column=1, row=2)
        first_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)
        second_entry.grid(column=2, row=2)


    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

appstart = GUI()
appstart.start()
```

It may be helpful to use the grid method to organize your widgets more efficiently. You can see in the packing area how you can select a column and row for placing the widget. In your code, the widgets are being packed over each other. This code will produce two labels and two entry boxes.Specifically, a label and then a entry to it's right. You can obviously manipulate them more, but I would go to effbot.org for a good resource.